# lower bound for an integer inequality in randomized 3SAT proof

Tags: inequality, algorithms

I'm having trouble seeing why an inequality holds in a section of a proof for solving MAX-3SAT by a [randomized algorithm](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp11/cse202-a/lecture17-final.pdf).

So given non-negative integer $k$, we define non negative integer $k'$ to be the largest natural number strictly less than $\frac{7k}{8}$. Then it goes on to say that the following inequality, $ \frac{1}{8} \leq \frac{7k}{8} - k'$, hold by properties of integers.

I'm not seeing why this is obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show $$1 \leq^{?} 7k-8k'$$
You have $$8k'<7k$$
Therefore $$7k-8k' >8k'-8k' = 0$$

Since $7k-8k' > 0$ and it is integer, it must be $\geq 1$.